# Alternative to redux-form dispatch change action in react-final-form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-final-form

I'm asked to migrate from redux-form to react-final-form.
I want to know if there is a way to replace all dispatch change actions of redux-form with a reasonable solution.

Found a solution (work around):
Attach form mutators to window object and use it.
I have tried it but it doesn't seem practical and standard.